# How do I navigate from a project uri in Rascal to the files it contains?

Tags: rascal

I would like to parse all the files in a project.
Suppose I have a location like |project://p2-SnakesAndLadders|, how can I navigate to the files in the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locations have an `ls` field, so you could type something like

```
|project://p2-SnakesAndLadders|.ls
```

to get back all the files and directories at the root level of the project as a list. You can then use functions `isFile` and `isDirectory` (both of which are in the prelude, so they are available by default) to distinguish between file and directory locations.

Comment: In util::FileSystem there exists also a function, crawl, to construct an in memory model of the file system.